# Background colour value between JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

I am trying to get the background colour of a coloured box when clicked  and subsequently storing it in a variable using either JavaScript or jQuery. Although it is trivial to get this information, what I am noticing is, JavaScript and jQuery show it in a slightly different manner.

For example, the coloured box that I am using is red (In the CSS, I am giving the background-color: red). Therefore, when I click the box with an id (`#box`) using the following code in JavaScript

```
var bColour = document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor;
```

`console.log(bColour)` gives me the value as `red`.

Whereas the same in jQuery

```
var bColour = $(#box).css("background-color");
```

`console.log(bColour)` gives me the value as `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

Is there a way for jQuery to display the `bColour` value identical to what JavaScript shows?

Comment: jQuery probably uses `getComputedStyle` which returns the computed style etc. Anyway, colors returned from the browser *can* be in whatever format the browser decides to return, and can't really be relied upon being a certain format.

Comment: "Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)." From [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Also note, `document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor` will return value only if `inline-css` is applied else empty string will be returned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.css` uses `getComputedStyle` function. **[ref](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/css/var/getStyles.js)**

There is no difference between  `getComputedStyle(Object).getPropertyValue(Property)` and `jQuery.css`

for example

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor
// return red;

getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv")).getPropertyValue("background-color");
// return rgb(255, 0, 0);

$('#myDiv').css("backgroundColor")
// return rgb(255, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Question: _Is there a way for jQuery to display the bColour value identical to what JavaScript shows_ This does not answer the question.

Comment: @RayonDabre unfortunately, there is no jQuery function for getting uncomputed value.